# Where can I get a display screen with 30 Hz or less refresh rate?

Tags: lcd, camera, tv, crt, pixels

I am experimenting with a camera recording a display screen.
Based on what I have read - camera recording a screen will have flicker if the refresh rate and frame rates are not synced.

My mobile camera records at 30fps. I wish to check the amount of flicker if the refresh rate is 30 Hz or less.

For this purpose where could I get a display with 30 Hz refresh rate ?

In case finding such equipment is not possible, how can I create one ?

Can I transform a video in such a way that it comes across as a lower refresh rate display to the amera to check for flicker?

Comment: You can generate a video signal with a simple pattern using an FPGA + some peripherals. Get some simple FPGA dev kit with VGA output and read up on how to generate a VGA signal. Yet it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Sounds good. I am going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

The information you're referring to is outdated. Flickering, banding, and other artifacts caused by refresh rate issues is primarily seen on CRT monitors -- LCDs are largely unaffected.

If you want to reproduce this issue intentionally for the purposes of an experiment, you will probably need to find an old CRT monitor. The effects created by a monitor of this type cannot be reproduced accurately on an LCD.

Comment: Okay. If the refresh rate and frame rates are highly unsynced still, an LCD will be unaffected ? Why are LCDs unaffected ?

Comment: CRTs have to be refreshed because the phosphor fades quickly; pixels in an LCD don't need the same sort of constant updates to stay visible. (And FWIW: The problem arises when the refresh rate and frame rates are _almost_ synchronized. If they're "highly unsynced", there's no problem.)

Comment: Hey @duskwuff 
I am stuck on this particular problem, need your advice on specific issues. Will it be okay if I mail you at your email mentioned on your profile ?